# What happens when you exceed 999999 points in Super Mario Bros.?

Tags: super-mario-bros

I am implementing a replica of the classic *Super Mario Bros.* in the Unity game engine. The problem is, I do not have a Nintendo Entertainment System.

I somehow found out that getting 100 coins will get you an extra 1UP (life), *but what about the score?*

**There are 6 available decimal spots for the score:**

[image: Score]

So what happens if the score exceeds 999999?

[image: Too much score]

Comment: NES emulators are widely available to try with.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Nothing special happens when going past 999,999 other than it just displays 7 digits instead.
[image: 1000100 score]
[Source](https://youtu.be/52HejkRec2s?t=1980)

Answer (score 112):

I quickly checked in an emulator since I didn't know either.

SMB1 stores the score in [BCD encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal), using 6 bytes, one for each digit - excluding the units, since score granularity does not go below multiples of 50.

If you have a score of 123,450, the bytes will be `00 01 02 03 04 05`.

**The first `00` byte is reserved for properly handling millions.** If you ever get scores between 1,000,000 and 9,999,950, there will simply be another digit displayed in front of the always visible 0's:

[image]

(The 6 bytes ahead of the marked ones are the TOP score, and the 6 following the Player 2 score.)

Technically, the maximum score possible is 9,999,990, 40 points above the maximum legal score which, as said, must be a multiple of 50.

[image]

If you exceed even this limit, the game will properly wrap over to 0, and the score is rendered as with a fresh game, with the millions-digit gone.

[image]

This is slightly spoiled by the `TOP- 000000` highscore display at the start screen, leaving a space for the millions.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115310/discussion-on-answer-by-ray-exceeding-999999-points-in-smb1).